# Thread notification don't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I can't find reason why ThreadA gets notification from ThreadB only when ThreadB completely finishes it's job. If I comment notify() ThreadA gets notification anyway.

Does ThreadB sends notification automatically when finishes it's job?

Why ThreadB does't notify ThreadA on time?

```
class ThreadA {
      public static void main(String [] args) {
         ThreadB b = new ThreadB();

         b.start();

         synchronized(b) 
         {

            try {
               System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
               b.wait();
               System.out.println("waiting done");
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

           System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);

        }
     }
  }





class ThreadB extends Thread {   
     int total=0; 
     public void run() {
        synchronized(this) 
        {


           for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
           {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ Integer.toString(i));
              total += i;
           }


           notify();
           System.out.println("notify done");

           for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
           {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ Integer.toString(i));
              total += i;
           }

        }
     }
  }
```

Output:

```
Waiting for b to complete...
Thread-0 0
Thread-0 1
Thread-0 2
Thread-0 3
Thread-0 4
Thread-0 5
Thread-0 6
Thread-0 7
Thread-0 8
Thread-0 9
notify done
Thread-0 0
Thread-0 1
Thread-0 2
Thread-0 3
Thread-0 4
Thread-0 5
Thread-0 6
Thread-0 7
Thread-0 8
Thread-0 9
Thread-0 10
Thread-0 11
Thread-0 12
Thread-0 13
Thread-0 14
Thread-0 15
Thread-0 16
Thread-0 17
Thread-0 18
Thread-0 19
waiting done
Total is: 235
```

Additional question - why Total is 235 in output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, *please* don't use `Thread` objects like this. `Thread` uses `wait` and `notify` itself, so you can easily end up with confusing signals.

The reason you're not seeing "waiting done" until the end is that although `ThreadB.run` calls `notify()`, it then keeps going *within the `synchronized` block*. The `wait()` method won't return until it can reacquire the monitor - which it can't do until the end of the synchronized block.

The total is simply the total having added up all the numbers - it looks like you've actually run with a second limit of 20, not 10... and (0 + 1 + 2 + ... 9) + (0 + 1 + 2 + ... 19) is 235. It's not clear why you'd expect anything else.